# Unable to trigger typeahead function

Tags: javascript, php, typeahead.js

I wanted to add a typeahead function by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0H6myhWkfA).  The following is how I coded.  When I check the control.log, I don't see anything returning.  It seems the typeahead function never gets called as I tested the data searching php and it does work.  Can anyone point me out what I did wrong?  Thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta chatset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="well">
    <input type="text" class="span3" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#typeahead").typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'source.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
              control.log(data);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['query'])) { 
    $db_host="localhost"; 
    $db_username="myuser"; 
    $db_pass="mypassword"; 
    $db_name="mydb"; 
    mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("$db_name") 
      or die ("Database not found"); 
    $query=$_POST['query']; 
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT prvname FROM prv WHERE prvname LIKE '%{$query}%'") 
      or die(mysql_error()); 
    $array=array(); 
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
      $array[]=$row['prvname']; 
    } 
    echo json_encode($array); 
  } 
?>
```

Comment: There are scattered spaces all over your code, is that just here or in your actual code? e.g. `$ _POST`, `m ysql_query`, etc.. Does the JS make the request to the PHP code?

Comment: The scattered spaces are just on the code I posted as I tried to tidy them up.  I don't think the JS has been called because I added an alert right after the line '$("#typeahead").typeahead({' and it didn't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typeahead function expects two arguments, so if you don't need to pass any typeahead option you can pass null as the first argument:

```
$(function() {
  $("#typeahead").typeahead(null, {
    source: function(query, process) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'source.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thx. I added null as the first argument and the JS seems get triggered, but now I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: control is not defined" on the control.log(data) line.  As per the demo, I should expect to see data returned from the searching PHP.

Comment: I edited the source code it's console.log instead of control.log :)

Comment: Chrome developer showed 2 errors.  I expanded it and it showed (anonymous fuction) @ jquery.min.js:4.  Is that what the problem was?

Comment: The ReferenceError problem was just a typo.

Comment: Thx, cesarwbr.  Now I can see the data returned in console.  As per the demo, I should see returned data on the page if I changed from Console.log(data) to process(data); but it didn't show anything.

Comment: It is working as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/8fxv4zxo/
Maybe it's your server data.

Comment: Yes, you sample does work.  I do see correct data returned (when I use console.log(data) ) so I assume that searching PHP is able to return what I needed.  It just somehow to showing anything on the page.  Would that be version issue?

Comment: Can be. Try to use the typeahead version 0.11.1: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js

Comment: I found it.  It works if I changed async to false but then I see "XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."  I don't know what it means.  Do I have to bother this message?

Comment: Yes, it can cause future problems. The best way to do it is to use Bloodhound typeahead.js suggestion engine and implement your typeahead like this example: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote

Comment: Thanks again,  I did find the link you mentioned but my knowledge in javascript is too limit to incorporate my code too that sample.  Just wondering if you are aware of any similar sample I can reference to.